# Is is possible to elevate security in IE .NET Add-on?

Tags: c#, .net, security, internet-explorer

I have a C#/.NET (VS2010) IE add-on which uses `Marshal.GetActiveObject()` to a running instance of an application (COM object) and then send commands to it via the `Invoke()` method. In XP it works fine. In W7/Vista, it requires both IE and the target application to be "Run as Administrator" or else it generates the exception:

```
[Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT:0x8000401E3 MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))]
```

Here's the code:

```
private void _BtnPlace_onclick(IHTMLEventObje)
{
    ....
    ....
    object AutoCADApp = null;
    try
    {
        // Does not return the object from the Running Objects Table unless run 'As Administrator'

        AutoCADApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application");
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to locate a running version of AutoCAD on this machine. Please make sure AutoCAD is running.\n\n [" + ex.Message + "]\n", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        return;
     } 

    object acadDoc = GetProperty(AutoCADApp, "ActiveDocument");
    InvokeMethod(acadDoc, "SendCommand", keyin);
}
```

Any ideas on how to address the security issues to make this add-on run in W7/Vista (asking it to prompt for elevated privileges is ok)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a shoot in the dark, but did you read this code project article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/ElevatedPrivilegesDemand.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A few points to think about:

1. Use early binding instead of reflection, invoking methods.
2. Check if some other code needing the 'Running As Administrator' privilege.
3. Try the .NET `SendStringToExecute()` instead.
4. Check if the command you were trying to invoke has some security
       concerns.